# Capybara, Poltergeist, PhantomJS, evaluate_script, callback

Tags: phantomjs, capybara, poltergeist

I am using the following code, which uses the [imagesLoaded](https://imagesloaded.desandro.com/#vanilla-javascript) package with a callback to tell me when an element with a particular csspath has finished loading all of its images:

```
imagesLoadedScript = "imagesLoaded( '#{csspath}', { background: true }, function(message) { console.log('PHANTOM CLIENT REPORTING: #{csspath} Images Loaded'); return message; })"
imagesLoadedScript = imagesLoadedScript.strip.gsub(/\s+/,' ')
@session.evaluate_script(imagesLoadedScript)
```

The timing of the console.log statement, on inspection of PhantomJS logs with debug on, indicates that Capybara/Poltergiest is not waiting for the images to load, as expected, before it moves on to the next statement. I also cannot return a true (or false) value from inside the callback as I would like.

Capybara responds with

```
{"command_id":"678f1e2e-4820-4631-8cd6-413ce6f4b66f","response":"(cyclic structure)"}
```

Anyone have any ideas on how to return a value from inside a callback in a function executed via evaluate_script?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

TLDR; You can't

`evaluate_script` doesn't support asynchronous functions - you must return the result you want from the function passed in. One way to do what you want would be to execute the `imagesLoaded` script and have the callback set a global variable, and then loop on an evaluate_script fetching the result of the global until it's what you want - A very basic implementation would be something like

```
imagesLoadedScript = "window.allImagesLoaded = false; imagesLoaded( '#{csspath}', { background: true }, function() { window.my_images_loaded = true })"
@session.execute_script(imagesLoadedScript)
while !@session.evaluate_script('window.allImagesLoaded')
  sleep 0.05
end
```

Obviously this could be made more flexible with a timeout ability, etc.

A second option would to write a custom capybara selector type for images with a `loaded` filter, although with the need for background image checking it would become pretty complicated and probably too slow to be useful.

Comment: Thanks Thomas I posted my solution above. Took me a while to realize I was trying to do something impossible.

Comment: @Tom That'll work too -  you could also just do something like adding a class to the `html/body` element rather than inserting new elements into the page (which could screw up CSS if you're doing anything with `nth-child` selectors, etc).

Comment: @Tom - FYI, Capybara will probably support this use case in its next release - https://github.com/teamcapybara/capybara/pull/1927 - Not sure how long after Poltergeist will support it though

Answer (score 0):

Just in case someone finds this later.

I did roughly what Thomas Walpole suggested in his answer, in a more roundabout fashion, but taking advantage of Poltergeist's inherent waiting capabilities;

```
#to check that the target has loaded its images, run images loaded
#after a small timeout to allow the page to get the images
#append a marker div to the dom if the images have successfully loaded
imagesLoadedScript = "var item = document.querySelector('#{csspath}');
                      window.scroll(0, item.offsetTop);
                      function imagesDone(path, fn) {
                        imagesLoaded( path, function(instance) {
                           console.log('PHANTOM CLIENT REPORTING: ' + path + ' Images Loaded');
                           fn(true);
                        })
                      }
                      setTimeout(function(){ 
                         imagesDone('#{csspath}', function(done) { 
                           var markerDiv = document.createElement('div'); 
                           markerDiv.id = 'ImagesLoadedMarker'; 
                           document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].appendChild(markerDiv); 
                         });
                      }, 1000)"

#then we strip the new lines and spaces that we added to make it readable 
imagesLoadedScript = imagesLoadedScript.strip.gsub(/\s+/,' ')
#now we just execute the script as we do not need a return value
@session.execute_script(imagesLoadedScript)
#then we check for the marker, using capybara's inbuilt waiting time
if @session.has_xpath? "//*[@id ='ImagesLoadedMarker']"
   Rails.logger.debug "!!!!! PhantomClient: Images Loaded Reporting: #{csspath} Images Loaded: Check Time #{Time.now} !!!!!"
   @session.save_screenshot(file_path, :selector => csspath)
else
   Rails.logger.debug "!!!!! PhantomClient: Images Loaded Reporting: #{csspath} Images NOT Loaded: Check Time #{Time.now} !!!!!"
   @session.save_screenshot(file_path, :selector => csspath)
end
```